# File saver is deprecated. How to resolve this issue from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, angular11, filesaver.js

Working on filesaver, while running SONAR QUBE it shows " 'fileSaver' is deprecated. use `{ autoBom: false }` as the third argument "

```
 this.http.get(`getTemplate/${doc.id}`, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        fileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([data], { type: this.fileType }), doc.docName)
```

error :- 'fileSaver' is deprecated. use `{ autoBom: false }` as the third argument

Even if I use autobom:false it still shows the same

**Here is the code for autobom**

```
this.http.get(`getDocument/${doc.docId}`, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.fileType });
        fileSaver.saveAs(blob, doc.docName,false);
```

'saveAs' is deprecated. use `{ autoBom: false }` as the third argumentWhy is this an issue?

'fileSaver' is deprecated. use `{ autoBom: false }` as the third argument Why is this an issue?

Comment: if i use autobom false even then it is showing the same

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I fixed by importing only the function.

For ts

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

saveAs(blob, doc.docName);
```

For js

```
const { saveAs } = require('file-saver');
```

I think that this sonar issue is because the browsers do not natively support interface.

Comment: It works! The warning disappears!

Answer (score 0):

It should be the setting of `autoBom`, not just `false`:

```
fileSaver.saveAs(blob, doc.docName, { autoBom: false });
```

---

See comment from @leokom.

Comment: even if i add this it still shows the issue

Comment: @hanusaikrishna there is a false positive issue in Sonar-JS, see: https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/3862